# Appropriate datastructure for flyweight

Tags: java, search, design-patterns, data-structures, flyweight-pattern

I am trying to apply the flyweight pattern in a program that generates clouds. I have a class that represents intrinsic states of clouds. A cloud type is defined by its attributes :

```
class CloudType {
    float size;
    float altitude;
    String color;
    String texture;

   public void display(x, y) {}

}

class ConcreteCloud {
    float x;
    float y;
    CloudType cloudType;

    void display() {
        cloudeType.display(x, y);
    }
}
```

I would like to create a CloudType factory that takes these characteristics as arguments and returns the corresponding instance of CloudType if it exists, else create and store it beforehand.

```
class CloudTypeFactory {
    //  SomeContainer<CloudType> container;

    public CloudType getCloudType(float size, float altitude, String color, String texture) {
        CloudType instance = // container get corresponding cloudType
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new CloudeType(size, altitude, color, texture);
            container.add(instance);
        }
        return instance;
    }

}
```

**The problem:**

I have doubts concerning which container to use and consequently the architecture itself. A HashSet could be used, but the search complexity gets proportional to the number of attributes in CloudType , which doesn't seem right. In examples I read online, authors use a HashMap with the key being the name of the CloudType: this defeats the purpose IMO as there might be an infinite number of cloud types in this case.

Answer (score 0):

1. Implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` for the `CloudType` class, so that you can store instances in a Map.
2. Use the hash code as the key.
3. Implement the hash code algorithm so that you can pass `size`, `altitude`, `color`, and `texture` to it.
4. Use the four arguments to generate a hash key to look up a `CloudType`.

Something like this.

```
class CloudType {
    float size;
    float altitude;
    String color;
    String texture;

    private static final Map<Integer, CloudType> CACHE = new HashMap<>();

    private CloudType(float size, float altitude, String color, String texture) {
        this.size = size;
        this.altitude = altitude;
        this.color = color;
        this.texture = texture;
    }

    public static CloudType lookup(float size, float altitude, String color, String texture) {
        int hashKey = hashCode(size, altitude, color, texture);
        return CACHE.computeIfAbsent(hashKey, k -> new CloudType(size, altitude, color, texture));
    }

    public void display(float x, float y) {}

    //TODO generate equals() method

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return hashCode(size, altitude, color, texture);
    }

    private static int hashCode(float size, float altitude, String color, String texture) {
        return Objects.hash(size, altitude, color, texture);
    }
}
```